# Can't import Java class?

Tags: java, class, import, package

[image: IDE Snapshot]

The screenshot is the error I am receiving. I am trying to use the class ConnectDB contained within the package CIS4362Connect1, in the class AdminManager in the package myconnectoracle. Why can't I import this class?

Comment: OT: You should change the name of your packages.

Comment: Is ConnectDB a public class?

Comment: Be sure that ConnectDB is of the type `public`, not 'private`. Also, as a future tip, try not to have class names be the same as your package name.

Comment: Probably not the problem but check if you are not mixing 1 (the digit) and l (the lowercase L), you never know.

Comment: include the stracktrace, not a screenshot of your IDE

Comment: Hi all.  I changed the name of my class and I also moved AdminManager under the package which contains ConnectDB.  However, now I'm being told by the IDE that it cannot find the class.  Here is a new screenshot.

http://i.imgur.com/YgvE8jA.png

Comment: Is there any 'package CIS....' in your ConnectDB.java file?

Comment: RyanPiveteau: Please just copy-paste the error next time. It's annoying to have to load the image, especially on a mobile platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As comments above indicate, it is possible that your `ConnectDB` is not public, in order to use that close outside of the its `package`, it must be declared `public`
Please refer to: **[Access control](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)** documentation*

---

**EDITED:** (Solution)

The problem is that packages are case sensitive, you have a different case in both packages declaration.

inside the ConnectDB class you maybe have `cis` in lower case.

Comment: ConnectDB is most definitely declared as public.

I had updated this in the comments and I changed some things based on the users' recommendation.  Here is a screenshot, showing where I moved the classes, with a new error.

http://i.imgur.com/YgvE8jA.png

Comment: Then it doesn't exist... or it is in a different project not related to this project.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to post the code to here, so I had to take another screenshot.  I hope it isn't too much of an inconvenience.

http://i.imgur.com/3oS9f8J.png

Comment: You are correct!  I had no idea and was slamming my head against the desk.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell,  the class you are looking for is not defined in the current project. Try referencing the project with the package you are looking for in the libraries, or just move the package/class.

Answer (score 0):

I just got a very similar issue with one of my class being unexplicably unimportable. I tried building the project anyways, and it did build successfuly, despite errors showing everywhere.

Moving the package to another location within my ide, and then moving it back to where it was supposed to be located somehow solved the issue for me.